# Simple C library for plotting a direction field (slope field) and euler method

Tags: linux, library, math, vector-graphics, c

I am looking for a simple and easy-to-use library for plotting a large amount of line segments in my C program. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular license restrictions to prevent using ploticus, gnu plot or the plotting code from mtcelledit? They have lgpl or gpl licenses iirc.